# Vote for synonyms on the synonyms page?

Tags: feature-request, tagging

The page for [tag synonyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) is a very useful place to see which synonyms are being proposed and vote for them.

However, right now, it seems that you have to go into each individual info page of each synonym in order to vote. Would it be possible to allow voting right from the page listing all pending tag synonyms?

Comment: And while you're there, could you please down-vote my suggestion of `latex2e -> latex`, I did that long ago before the recent discussion on tags.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a place to discuss *specific* suggestions?

For example, I'm not sure about the 'ams -> amsmath' suggestion.  The AMS has more packages than just 'amsmath', in particular they have their 'amsref' stuff.  I would regard the 'ams' tag as ambiguous, and so not as one that is synonymous with another tag.  Rather, whenever 'ams' rears its ugly head, it should be retagged to an *appropriate* tag.

---

To expand on that, synonymous tags should really be synonymous.  I think that the most obvious examples being singular to plural, or no-hyphens to hyphens.  Where a tag is ambiguous or just plain useless, the questions should be retagged and the tag effectively dropped.

Comment: Actually agree with all the points (and I suggested that synonym!). But mostly about the need to have a place to discuss synonyms. Maybe synonyms should be discussed in meta before being even suggested?

Comment: @Juan A. Navarro: It seems that discussion on synonyms is taking place in the "set of tags" discussion.  I'll copy across this post there.

Comment: @Juan A. Navarro: And on the procedural point, certainly when a synonym is proposed then there ought to be a standard place for it to be announced, plus a brief explanation of why.  (I'd be quite happy for people to go ahead with making the proposal official, but we need to be sure that everyone gets a chance to know about it and the counter-argument - if any - put.)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that there are less than 10 users that can currently vote on tags, perhaps it would be prudent to wait with this retagging effort. I know that it can be changed in the future, but these type of things seldom are. (I might be biased since I do not have the required rep to vote...)

Comment: The idea is to get standard tag usage as soon as possible to avoid duplicate tags. You can express your opinion on the discussion question (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302/our-set-of-tags). The currently suggested synonyms are all (as far as I know) uncontroversial.

Comment: As you see in Andrews answer, this is incorrect.