# StackExchange secret pages

Tags: discussion, big-list

So I recently learned about the [review page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review). What other unlinked goodies pages exist?

Comment: I opened a [feature-request for a sitemap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79977/156875) which should list all of this pages.

Comment: Review is linked to from [http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/77](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/77).

Comment: Related thread on meta.SO: [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/155585).

Comment: [‍](http://www.google.com)

Comment: @Seamus: See, that was shorter than 15 characters `:-)`

Answer (score 14):

- See a breakdown of your reputation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation
- User ranking per week, month, year and all time (not exactly secret, but not linked from here): http://stackexchange.com/leagues/29/week/tex
- A little known feature -- formatting key combinations: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

  `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>`
- If you click on the "days" against the "visited" field in your user profile, you can see when exactly you failed to get your daily fix on TeX-SE.
- Tags on meta can also be linked: `[tag-meta:status-bydesign]`

Comment: What is the key combination for? The *Meta* key is the left Windows key, isn't it?

Comment: @Martin: This is just an example: you can write anything you want between the <kbd> tags.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realized that you meant the XML syntax. :-) In this context I thought this combination brings you from the main to the meta page or something like that.

Comment: Wow, the list of days that I visited various SE sites is rather scary to contemplate.

Comment: <kbd>hello. testing. this works or does' not work in comments? . </kbd>

Comment: <kbd>testinbg</kbd>

Answer (score 10):

- The [tag synonyms page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) is a useful list of suggested tag synomyns, alread mentioned [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309/vote-for-synonyms-on-the-synonyms-page).
- See also the [{TeX} site data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries) and the [{TeX} meta site data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/texmeta/queries).
- The [Inbox page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/inbox) gives a list of comments and chat messages for the user. Besides messages from the {TeX} site, its meta site and its chat it lists messages from all the stackexchange sites including SO.

Pages, for which I suggest we should edit them:

- [How to ask](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) (pointing to minimal working example, perhaps to 1-2 excellently written questions as examples)
- [How to answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) (mentioning screenshots, linking packages to CTAN, pointing to excellently written answers as examples and to answer style discussion on meta)

These two pages could be linked from the [FAQ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if we have everything in one CW answer?

Comment: @Hendrik, Stefan: IMHO the whole thread should be a CW. On some point we should create some CW sitemap out of all these links.

Comment: @Martin, @Hendrik: yes, we usually decide to use CW for such big-list threads. A summarizing CW post at the top (accepted) would be fine. I don't see a harm though in posting answers while collecting - this way votes (also CW) would show which page are the most liked or most popular, kind of sorting.

Comment: @Stefan: Ah, good, I didn't look at it this way.

Comment: @Stefan: I added one sentence to the inbox description; maybe you find a better formulation.

Comment: @Hendrik: thanks, additionally mentioning the other SE sites is useful. Now I added the how-to pages.

Answer (score 10):

`http://<site>/posts/<postid>/timeline`. For example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1001/timeline

Answer (score 6):

You can get a data dump from your reputation at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation

The *ninja search options* are listed under https://tex.stackexchange.com/search which also appears on an empty search text. It's not really hidden, but I just found it recently.

Not a secret page but useful to know: If the mouse pointer is placed above the post date, i.e. the "answered *x*  *unit* ago", the full date and time is displayed.

List of suggested tag synonyms: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Answer (score 5):

In comments, you can insert shorthand links:

> - `[meta]` – link to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name  (e.g. "Super User Meta"). Does nothing if the site doesn't have (or already is) a Meta site.
> - `[main]` – like `[meta]`, just the other way around.
> - `[edit]` – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).
> - `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]` – link to the given tag's page. Link text is the name of the tag. `meta-tag` only works on meta sites.
> - `[faq]`, `[faq#anchor]`, `[meta-faq]`, `[meta-faq#anchor]` – link to the FAQ. Link text is "faq" (capitalization is respected). `meta-faq` only works    on meta sites.
> - `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metaso]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given site. Link text is the site name.
> - `[chat]` – link to the current site's chat site, the link text being "{site name} Chat".
> - `[ask]`, `[answer]` – link to the "How to Ask" / "How to Answer" page.
> - `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for Ask Ubuntu.

(https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

This feature is discussed at meta.so: [Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000). As a little demo, I'm adding the demo comment from that thread to this post. Its source is:

> "On [main], you are expected to write proper English (as advertised on [english.se]), but here on [metaso] it's more important to have freehand circles, so please [edit] your post, otherwise I'll have to flag you (see the [FAQ#flagging]). If you're unsure how to use your keyboard, [su] is the right place to ask. There's no Q&A site about unicorns yet, but you can suggest one on [area51.se]."

Comment: "On [main], you are expected to write proper English (as advertised on [english.se]), but here on [metase] it's more important to have freehand circles, so please [edit] your post, otherwise I'll have to flag you (see the [FAQ#flagging]). If you're unsure how to use your keyboard, [su] is the right place to ask. There's no Q&A site about unicorns yet, but you can suggest one on [area51.se]."